# Problema com formatação de string em Python

Tags: python, string

Primeiramente gostaria de informar que: (a) sou contador e programo apenas para me ajudar em tarefas com grande massa de dados, então meu código abaixo não vai ser um código de profissional, e (b) essa é minha primeira pergunta por aqui, então se faltar informações que sejam importantes para a resposta peço desculpas.

Vamos lá

Estou fazendo um programa em Python para me auxiliar na correção de um arquivo de escrituração contábil digital - ECD. e após fazer as correções necessárias (que ficaram arquivadas em uma matriz (lista de listas)) chamada I155Reduzido, quero exportar para um arquivo chamado ECD Corrigido.

No momento em que estou escrevendo no arquivo o registro corrigido aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "corrigirECD_v2.py", line
>   288, in 
>       I155Reduzido[int(i)][9] + '|\n') ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

o código que gera esse erro é:

```
276    i = 0
277    with open(arquivoECD, encoding="utf8") as ECD:
278        for linha in ECD:
279            if str(I155Reduzido[int(i)][0]) == str(contadorRegistro):
280                registroCorrigido = ('|I155|' +
281                                     I155Reduzido[int(i)][1] + '|' +
282                                     I155Reduzido[int(i)][2] + '|' +
283                                     '{:.2f}'.format(str(I155Reduzido[int(i)][4]).replace('.', ',')) + '|' +
284                                     I155Reduzido[int(i)][5] + '|' +
285                                     '{:.2f}'.format(str(I155Reduzido[int(i)][12]).replace('.', ',')) + '|' +
286                                     '{:.2f}'.format(str(I155Reduzido[int(i)][14]).replace('.', ',')) + '|' +
287                                     '{:.2f}'.format(str(I155Reduzido[int(i)][8]).replace('.', ',')) + '|' +
288                                     I155Reduzido[int(i)][9] + '|\n')
289                ECD_corrigido.writelines(registroCorrigido)
290                if i < (len(I155Reduzido)-1):
291                    i = i + 1
292
293            else:
294                ECD_corrigido.writelines(linha)
295            contadorRegistro = contadorRegistro + 1
```

Pergunta: o que eu estou fazendo de errado na linha em 288, se a linha 284 tem a mesma caracteristica? o que eu estou deixando passar?

Estou usando o ubuntu 19.10 e python3.7

Agradeço antecipadamento o auxílio

Comment: Qual era o objetivo de formatar uma string com o formato `{:.2f}`? Esse formato é para números decimais.

Comment: Woss, eu pego a seguinte linha de um arquivo TXT |I155|2110310001||1234,56|D|12,34|1,23|1234,56|D|, preciso fazer uma soma com os valores dessa linha, sendo que o python trabalha com "." para os decimais, mas o layout que a receita federal estipulou e com "," para decimais. Então eu converto a vírgula para ponto na entrada e na hora de exportar os valores (que é o trecho do código) eu tenho que converter de ponto para vírgula novamente. Por isso a conversão de alguns campos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente utilizar o locale para a utilizar a separação de decimal.

```py
import locale

locale.setLocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

Aí na formatação do número não será preciso fazer o replace. Por exemplo:

```py
valor = 9.93 # Decimal em python
print('{:n}'.format(valor)) # resultado: 9,93
```

Espero que isso possa ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Troque os parses de str para float:

De

```
str(I155Reduzido[int(i)][4]).replace('.', ','))
```

Para

```
float(I155Reduzido[int(i)][4]).replace('.', ','))
```